# Scrabble basic score

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have been asked to write a program that allows a user to enter many words as he likes, calculates the value of the words and only print the max value word. So, ‘a’ would have a value of 1 and ‘aa’ a value of 2, i dont know how to sum the scores of each letter.
i got this:

```
word = input("Input your word ' ")

words = word.split()

score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
          "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
          "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
          "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
          "x": 8, "z": 10}

total=score[words]

print(total)
```

but i get error and dont know how to continue, help please :(

Comment: You need to iterate through the list `words` and total the values based on the 'word'

Comment: Please, share your code with us. We can't help you if we don't know what the error is or in what part of the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using While Loop**

```
word = input("Input your words separated by ',' ")

words = word.split(',')

score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
          "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
          "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
          "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
          "x": 8, "z": 10}

max_score = 0
max_score_word = ''

wd_len = len(words)
word_count = 0
while word_count < wd_len: #you need to iterate thru each word
    total = 0  #reset counter to calculate score for each word
    wd = words[word_count].lower() #store the current word to process
    letter_len = len(wd) #find the length of the word
    letter_count = 0 #reset counter to iterate thru the word
    while letter_count < letter_len: #iterate thru each letter in the word
        letter = wd[letter_count]
        if letter in score: #check if letter is alphabet
            total = total + score[letter] #add to total
        letter_count +=1 #increase counter for letter to process next letter
    if max_score < total: #check if this score is a new high score
        max_score = total #reset high score with current score
        max_score_word = wd #keep track of the word with the highest score
    word_count +=1 #increase counter for word to process next word

#once you are done with everything, print the word and score
        
print('The word with the maximum score of :',max_score, 'is : ',max_score_word)
```

**Using For Loop**

You need to iterate through the words and then thru the letters in the word. You need to check the score of each word against the max score of previous words. If the current score is the highest, then that's the word you need to print.

To accomplish the homework, here's how you go about doing it.

```
word = input("Input your words separated by ',' ")

words = word.split(',')

score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
          "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
          "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
          "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
          "x": 8, "z": 10}

max_score = 0
max_score_word = ''

for wd in words: #you need to iterate thru each word
    total = 0  #reset counter to calculate score for each word
    for letter in wd: #iterate thru each letter in the word
        if letter.lower() in score: #check if letter is alphabet
            total = total + score[letter.lower()] #add to total
    if max_score < total: #check if this score is a new high score
        max_score = total #reset high score with current score
        max_score_word = wd #keep track of the word with the highest score

#once you are done with everything, print the word and score
        
print('The word with the maximum score of :',max_score, 'is : ',max_score_word)
```

The output for the first time was:

```
Input your words separated by ',' good, morning, bad, zulu, income
The word with the maximum score of : 13 is :   zulu
```

The output for the second time was:

```
Input your words separated by ',' good, morning, bad, zulu, income, jack
The word with the maximum score of : 17 is :   jack
```

Comment: i cant use "for"

Comment: sorry, didnt realize that. updated to use while loop. I see that you can use while loop

Comment: please upvote and mark answer as correct if you think this solved the question.

Comment: tanks, btw is any way to do this without  { } ?

Comment: Yes, you can use a two lists. one with all the alphabets, and another with all the values. You check for the alphabet in one list and use the same index to get the value from the other index. Too messy but it can be done.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
word = input("Input your words separated by ','")
words = word.split(',')
print(words)
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, "x": 8, "z": 10}
biggest = ''
total_max = 0
for singleword in words:
    total = 0
    for letter in singleword:
        total += score[letter]
    if total > total_max:
        biggest = singleword
        total_max = total
print(f'{biggest=} {total_max=}')
```

```
**EXAMPLE:**
Input your words separated by ','
this is a test for biggest word
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'for', 'biggest', 'word']
biggest='biggest' total_max=11
```

Comment: You did great. Just one mistake. The ask is to find the word with the max value. So you need to reset total every time and then check if the score is greater than the previous scores. The word with the highest score is the one that should be printed.

Comment: but the problem is i cant use "for"

Comment: so this is FOR solution... i am sorry, i have no sense why to do this w/o FOR...

Comment: @Joe Ferndz -- you're right! i've edited the answer with total recoil and check if it greater than max result (total_max) or not